# Cocoapods: duplicate interface definition

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6, cocoapods

I' wrapped my private library into CocoaPods. It has dependency on ReactiveCocoa.

```
s.name =  'MineLibrary'
s.dependency 'ReactiveCocoa/Core'
s.source_files = 'Source/*.{h,m,swift}'
....
```

Some header files contain:

```
#import <ReactiveCocoa/RACSignal.h>
```

I include it in a new project:

```
use_frameworks!
....
pod 'ReactiveCocoa'
pod 'MineLibrary', :git => 'git@.....'
```

But when I compile the project, I'm getting this error:

```
duplicate interface definition for class 'RACStream'
duplicate interface definition for class 'RACSignal'


/Users/USER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-emcwpmbbuimotuftzijeemvngrvj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Pods/ReactiveCocoa.framework/Headers/RACStream.h:27:1: error: duplicate interface definition for class 'RACStream'

@interface RACStream : NSObject
^
/Users/USER/Workspace/Project/Pods/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/RACStream.h:27:12: note: previous definition is here
@interface RACStream : NSObject
```

How can it be solved?
P.S. I'm using CocoaPods 0.36.0.rc.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried updating to the latest release of CocoaPods? I noticed you mentioned you're using an outdated release candidate, which is possibly at fault here.

In general, here's what you need to do when creating and using a CocoaPod in your app:

1) In your CocoaPod, declare all of your dependencies in the pod spec, using `s.dependency` for each

2) In your app, use CocoaPods to manage all of of your app dependencies. That is, *don't* manually drag-and-drop libraries into your app. If you do, you risk creating duplicate classes with the ones that you drag-and-drop include.

3) In both your app and CocoaPod, depend on as flexible versions as you can. In general, you should at least allow for minor version updates, e.g. `pod 'PodName', '~> 1.0.0'`.

4) In your app's pod file, specify a target for your app and your unit test target, e.g.

```
target "MyApp" do
  # App pods...
end

target "MyAppTests", :exclusive => true do
  # Test pods...
end
```

If you have more than two targets, specify a target for each. Or, at the very least, specify a different target for unit tests, which will get the app injected into it.

Comment: Unfortunately i don't remember how issue was resolved, may be it really was due to cocoapods version. After that i never got this issue again.

Answer (score 26):

I was having this issue a while back, somebody imported a cocoapod header incorrectly.  Make sure you use bracket notation, E.G. rather than:
`#import "theUsefulClass.h"`
you should be using:
`#import <thePod/theUsefulClass.h>`

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, you can check the Symbol Navigator (Cmd-3) to see where the symbol is defined twice. This will allow you to make a decision about what to do. In my case, I found two symbols with the same name from two different libraries. Maybe one of these could have a prefix added to the symbol name to disambiguate the conflict.